# Is it possible to add searchview in recyclerview fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, searchview

This is my Home.java

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    dataInitialize();

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    MyAdapter2 myAdapter2 = new MyAdapter2(getContext(), catLabelArrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter2);

    myAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I also do have MyAdapter2 but I want to add a searchview filter inside a fragment with these on the Main activity not on the menu toolbar

```
private void dataInitialize() {

    catLabelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    newsHeading = new String[]{
            "Food",
            "Place",
            "Accesories",
    };
```

Comment: You can add EditText or AutoCompleteTextView above the RecyclerView in your  fragment xml layout. Then you add a listener and check for input changes and then filter RecyclerView according to it.

Comment: I already have Edittext bro, the only problem is I don't know how to implement searchview. Can you help me??